# VAADIN: MyAppWidgetset.nocache.js not found from filesystem or through class loader

Tags: java, tomcat, vaadin, war

I deploy the web-application on the tomcat-server from `intellij idea` here with these characteristics:

```
<component name="ArtifactManager">
  <artifact type="exploded-war" build-on-make="true" name="webrp:war exploded">
    <output-path>$PROJECT_DIR$/target/webrp-1.0</output-path>
    <root id="root">
      <element id="directory" name="WEB-INF">
        <element id="directory" name="classes">
          <element id="module-output" name="webrp" />
        </element>
        <element id="directory" name="lib">
          <element id="library" level="project" name="Maven: com.vaadin:vaadin-server:7.6.7" />
          <element id="library" level="project" name="Maven: com.vaadin:vaadin-sass-compiler:0.9.13" />
          <element id="library" level="project" name="Maven: com.vaadin.external.flute:flute:1.3.0.gg2" />
          <element id="library" level="project" name="Maven: com.yahoo.platform.yui:yuicompressor:2.4.8" />
          <element id="library" level="project" name="Maven: rhino:js:1.7R2" />
          <element id="library" level="project" name="Maven: com.vaadin:vaadin-shared:7.6.7" />
          <element id="library" level="project" name="Maven: com.vaadin.external.streamhtmlparser:streamhtmlparser-jsilver:0.0.10.vaadin1" />
          <element id="library" level="project" name="Maven: com.vaadin.external.google:guava:16.0.1.vaadin1" />
          <element id="library" level="project" name="Maven: org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3" />
          <element id="library" level="project" name="Maven: com.vaadin:vaadin-push:7.6.7" />
          <element id="library" level="project" name="Maven: com.vaadin.external.atmosphere:atmosphere-runtime:2.2.7.vaadin1" />
          <element id="library" level="project" name="Maven: com.vaadin.external.slf4j:vaadin-slf4j-jdk14:1.6.1" />
          <element id="library" level="project" name="Maven: org.w3c.css:sac:1.3" />
          <element id="library" level="project" name="Maven: com.vaadin:vaadin-themes:7.6.7" />
          <element id="library" level="project" name="Maven: org.tltv.gantt:gantt-addon:0.9.3" />
        </element>
      </element>
      <element id="javaee-facet-resources" facet="webrp/web/Web" />
    </root>
  </artifact>
</component>
```

As a result, I have an error:

```
Aug 09, 2016 9:51:40 AM com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet serveStaticResourcesInVAADIN
INFO: Requested resource [/VAADIN/widgetsets/ru.comp.webgrp.MyAppWidgetset/ru.comp.webgrp.MyAppWidgetset.nocache.js] not found from filesystem or through class loader. Add widgetset and/or theme JAR to your classpath or add files to WebContent/VAADIN folder.
```

those methods which have been described in interenete - do not help, and some are not suitable. as I understand the problem is that is not compiled vaadin.
The same error occurs when I add `gwt-compiler-output`

If I add the all output:

```
    <component name="ArtifactManager">
  <artifact type="exploded-war" build-on-make="true" name="webrp:war exploded">
    <output-path>$PROJECT_DIR$/target/webrp-1.0</output-path>
    <root id="root">
      <element id="directory" name="WEB-INF">
        <element id="directory" name="classes">
          <element id="module-output" name="webrp" />
        </element>
        <element id="directory" name="lib">
          <element id="library" level="project" name="Maven: com.vaadin:vaadin-server:7.6.7" />
          <element id="library" level="project" name="Maven: com.vaadin:vaadin-sass-compiler:0.9.13" />
          <element id="library" level="project" name="Maven: com.vaadin.external.flute:flute:1.3.0.gg2" />
          <element id="library" level="project" name="Maven: com.yahoo.platform.yui:yuicompressor:2.4.8" />
          <element id="library" level="project" name="Maven: rhino:js:1.7R2" />
          <element id="library" level="project" name="Maven: com.vaadin:vaadin-shared:7.6.7" />
          <element id="library" level="project" name="Maven: com.vaadin.external.streamhtmlparser:streamhtmlparser-jsilver:0.0.10.vaadin1" />
          <element id="library" level="project" name="Maven: com.vaadin.external.google:guava:16.0.1.vaadin1" />
          <element id="library" level="project" name="Maven: org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3" />
          <element id="library" level="project" name="Maven: com.vaadin:vaadin-push:7.6.7" />
          <element id="library" level="project" name="Maven: com.vaadin.external.atmosphere:atmosphere-runtime:2.2.7.vaadin1" />

.........................................

          <element id="library" level="project" name="Maven: org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:1.9.12" />
        </element>
      </element>
      <element id="javaee-facet-resources" facet="webrp/web/Web" />
      <element id="directory" name="VAADIN">
        <element id="directory" name="widgetsets">
          <element id="gwt-compiler-output" facet="webrp/gwt/GWT" />
        </element>
      </element>
    </root>
  </artifact>
</component>
```

So I get an error:

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet WebrpUIServlet
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/vaadin/server/BootstrapHandler.setupStandaloneDocument(Lcom/vaadin/server/BootstrapHandler$BootstrapContext;Lcom/vaadin/server/BootstrapPageResponse;)V @54: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'org/jsoup/nodes/DocumentType' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'org/jsoup/nodes/Node'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @54
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/vaadin/server/BootstrapHandler', 'com/vaadin/server/BootstrapHandler$BootstrapContext', 'com/vaadin/server/BootstrapPageResponse', 'org/jsoup/nodes/Document', 'org/jsoup/nodes/DocumentType' }
    stack: { 'org/jsoup/nodes/Element', 'org/jsoup/nodes/DocumentType' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2c12 4b12 4cb6 004d 2c12 4e12 4cb6 004d
    0x0000010: 2c12 4f09 b600 502c b600 514e bb00 5259
    0x0000020: 1253 121e 121e 2db6 0054 b700 553a 042d
    0x0000030: 03b6 0056 1904 b600 5757 2db6 0058 3a05
    0x0000040: 1905 1259 b600 5a12 5b12 5cb6 005d 125e
    0x0000050: 125f b600 5d57 1905 1259 b600 5a12 5b12
    0x0000060: 60b6 005d 125e 1261 b600 5d57 2bb6 0022
    0x0000070: 3a06 013a 0719 0613 0062 b600 63c0 0062
    0x0000080: 3a08 1906 1300 64b6 0063 c000 643a 0919
    0x0000090: 08c6 003e 1909 c600 39bb 0065 59bb 002c
    0x00000a0: 59b7 002d 1906 b600 66b6 0031 1267 b600
    0x00000b0: 3113 0062 b600 68b6 0031 1269 b600 3113
    0x00000c0: 0064 b600 68b6 0031 b600 32b7 006a bf19
    0x00000d0: 08c6 000f 1908 b900 6b01 003a 07a7 004a
    0x00000e0: 1909 c600 4519 09b9 006c 0100 3a0a 190a
    0x00000f0: b600 6dc0 006e 2bb6 0018 b900 6f02 003a
    0x0000100: 07a7 0026 3a0b bb00 3d59 bb00 2c59 b700
    0x0000110: 2d12 71b6 0031 190a b600 66b6 0031 b600
    0x0000120: 3219 0bb7 0072 bf19 07c6 0019 1905 1259
    0x0000130: b600 5a12 7312 74b6 005d 125e 1907 b600
    0x0000140: 5d57 2cb6 0075 bb00 7659 2bb6 0018 2bb6
    0x0000150: 0022 b700 77b6 0078 3a0a 190a c600 1019
    0x0000160: 0512 79b6 005a 190a b600 7a57 1905 127b
    0x0000170: b600 5a12 7c12 7db6 005d 127e b600 7a57
    0x0000180: 2bb6 007f 3a0b 190b c600 6a2a 2b19 0bb6
    0x0000190: 0080 3a0c 1905 1281 b600 5a12 8212 83b6
    0x00001a0: 005d 127c 1284 b600 5d12 85bb 002c 59b7
    0x00001b0: 002d 190c b600 3112 86b6 0031 b600 32b6
    0x00001c0: 005d 5719 0512 81b6 005a 1282 1287 b600
    0x00001d0: 5d12 7c12 84b6 005d 1285 bb00 2c59 b700
    0x00001e0: 2d19 0cb6 0031 1286 b600 31b6 0032 b600
    0x00001f0: 5d57 1906 1300 88b6 0063 c000 883a 0c19
    0x0000200: 0cc6 004d 190c b900 8901 003a 0d19 0d3a
    0x0000210: 0e19 0ebe 360f 0336 1015 1015 0fa2 0031
    0x0000220: 190e 1510 323a 112a 2b19 0619 11b7 008a
    0x0000230: 3a12 1905 128b b600 5a12 7c12 8cb6 005d
    0x0000240: 128d 1912 b600 5d57 8410 01a7 ffce 1906
    0x0000250: 1300 8eb6 0063 c000 8e3a 0d19 0dc6 0054
    0x0000260: 190d b900 8f01 003a 0e19 0e3a 0f19 0fbe
    0x0000270: 3610 0336 1115 1115 10a2 0038 190f 1511
    0x0000280: 323a 122a 2b19 0619 12b7 008a 3a13 1905
    0x0000290: 1281 b600 5a12 8212 90b6 005d 127c 127d
    0x00002a0: b600 5d12 8519 13b6 005d 5784 1101 a7ff
    0x00002b0: c72d b600 263a 0e19 0e12 9112 92b6 005d
    0x00002c0: 5719 0e12 93b6 0094 57b1               
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [238, 257] => handler: 260
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@207,{Object[#310],Object[#341],Object[#346],Object[#345],Object[#397],Object[#347],Object[#316],Object[#398],Object[#399],Object[#400]},{})
    same_frame(@224)
    full_frame(@260,{Object[#310],Object[#341],Object[#346],Object[#345],Object[#397],Object[#347],Object[#316],Object[#398],Object[#399],Object[#400],Object[#316]},{Object[#401]})
    chop_frame(@295,1)
    same_frame(@322)
    append_frame(@364,Object[#398])
    append_frame(@498,Object[#398])
    full_frame(@537,{Object[#310],Object[#341],Object[#346],Object[#345],Object[#397],Object[#347],Object[#316],Object[#398],Object[#399],Object[#400],Object[#398],Object[#398],Object[#402],Object[#403],Object[#403],Integer,Integer},{})
    full_frame(@590,{Object[#310],Object[#341],Object[#346],Object[#345],Object[#397],Object[#347],Object[#316],Object[#398],Object[#399],Object[#400],Object[#398],Object[#398],Object[#402]},{})
    full_frame(@629,{Object[#310],Object[#341],Object[#346],Object[#345],Object[#397],Object[#347],Object[#316],Object[#398],Object[#399],Object[#400],Object[#398],Object[#398],Object[#402],Object[#404],Object[#403],Object[#403],Integer,Integer},{})
    full_frame(@689,{Object[#310],Object[#341],Object[#346],Object[#345],Object[#397],Object[#347],Object[#316],Object[#398],Object[#399],Object[#400],Object[#398],Object[#398],Object[#402],Object[#404]},{})

    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServletService.createRequestHandlers(VaadinServletService.java:49)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.init(VaadinService.java:191)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.createServletService(VaadinServlet.java:317)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.init(VaadinServlet.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:828)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here it is WebrpUI:

```
@Theme("valo")
@Widgetset("ru.comp.webgrp.MyAppWidgetset")
@Title(value = "Планирование")
public class WebrpUI extends UI {

    private Navigator navigator;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        navigator = new Navigator(this, this);
        navigator.addView("", ResourcesView.class);
        navigator.addView("resources", ResourcesView.class);
    }

    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "WebrpUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = WebrpUI.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class WebrpUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>ru.comp</groupId>
        <artifactId>webrp</artifactId>
        <packaging>pom</packaging>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <name>webrp</name>

        <properties>
            <vaadin.version>7.6.7</vaadin.version>
            <vaadin.plugin.version>${vaadin.version}</vaadin.plugin.version>
            <jetty.plugin.version>9.2.3.v20140905</jetty.plugin.version>
            <project.source.version>1.7</project.source.version>
            <project.target.version>1.7</project.target.version>
            <project.encoding>UTF-8</project.encoding>
                    <resteasy.version>3.0.18.Final</resteasy.version>
        </properties>

        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>vaadin-addons</id>
                <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
                <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>atlassian-groups-public</id>
                <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/content/groups/public/</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                </snapshots>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                </releases>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>atlassian-public</id>
                <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                </snapshots>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                </releases>
            </repository>
        </repositories>

        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                    <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>

        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin.addon</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-charts</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.3</version>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.tltv.gantt</groupId>
                <artifactId>gantt-addon</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.18.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.18.Final</version>
            </dependency>
    <!--        <dependency>
                <groupId>comp</groupId>
                <artifactId>Resources</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>-->

        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>${project.encoding}</encoding>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>${project.encoding}</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        <!-- Exclude some unnecessary files generated by the GWT compiler. -->
                        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/gwt-unitCache/**,
                            WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF/**</packagingExcludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                        <webappDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets</webappDirectory>
                        <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
                        <compileReport>false</compileReport>
                        <style>OBF</style>
                        <strict>true</strict>
                        <runTarget>http://localhost:8080/webrp</runTarget>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>update-theme</goal>
                                <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                                <!-- disabled by default to use on-the-fly theme compilation -->
                                <!-- <goal>compile-theme</goal> -->
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6.1</version>
                    <!-- Clean up also any pre-compiled themes -->
                    <configuration>
                        <filesets>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/styles.css</include>
                                    <include>**/styles.scss.cache</include>
                                </includes>
                            </fileset>
                        </filesets>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <!-- The Jetty plugin allows us to easily test the development build by
                running jetty:run on the command line. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${jetty.plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>

            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
                    <!-- TODO Remove when http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/14924 is resolved -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                                <pluginExecutions>
                                    <pluginExecution>
                                        <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>
                                                vaadin-maven-plugin
                                            </artifactId>
                                            <versionRange>[7.1.11,)</versionRange>
                                            <goals>
                                                <goal>resources</goal>
                                                <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                                                <goal>compile</goal>
                                                <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                                                <goal>update-theme</goal>
                                            </goals>
                                        </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <action>
                                            <ignore></ignore>
                                        </action>
                                    </pluginExecution>
                                </pluginExecutions>
                            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>

        </build>

    </project>
```

Perhaps the problem is that when the `mvn clean install` and`mvn clean vaadin: compile` skipped steps:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ webrp ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\svn\tmpTrunk\webrp\target
[INFO] Deleting C:\svn\tmpTrunk\webrp\src\main\webapp\VAADIN\themes (includes = [**/styles.css, **/styles.scss.cache], excludes = [])
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- vaadin-maven-plugin:7.6.7:update-theme (default) @ webrp ---
[INFO] Theme processing is skipped
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- vaadin-maven-plugin:7.6.7:update-widgetset (default) @ webrp ---
[INFO] GWT compilation is skipped
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> vaadin-maven-plugin:7.6.7:compile (default) @ webrp >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- vaadin-maven-plugin:7.6.7:update-theme (default) @ webrp ---
[INFO] Theme processing is skipped
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< vaadin-maven-plugin:7.6.7:compile (default) @ webrp <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- vaadin-maven-plugin:7.6.7:compile (default) @ webrp ---
[INFO] GWT compilation is skipped
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ webrp ---
[INFO] Installing C:\svn\tmpTrunk\webrp\pom.xml to C:\Users\s\.m2\repository\ru\comp\webrp\1.0\webrp-1.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.162s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Aug 09 10:06:32 MSK 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/445M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Tell me how to solve the problem?

`mvn package`

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building webrp 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for jta:jta:jar:1.0.1 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/apache/velocity/velocity/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/apache/velocity/velocity/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 1.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public/com/google/guava/guava/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public/com/google/guava/guava/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 2.6 KB/sec)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- vaadin-maven-plugin:7.6.7:update-theme (default) @ webrp ---
[INFO] Theme processing is skipped
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- vaadin-maven-plugin:7.6.7:update-widgetset (default) @ webrp ---
[INFO] GWT compilation is skipped
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> vaadin-maven-plugin:7.6.7:compile (default) @ webrp >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- vaadin-maven-plugin:7.6.7:update-theme (default) @ webrp ---
[INFO] Theme processing is skipped
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< vaadin-maven-plugin:7.6.7:compile (default) @ webrp <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- vaadin-maven-plugin:7.6.7:compile (default) @ webrp ---
[INFO] GWT compilation is skipped
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.072s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Aug 09 12:08:32 MSK 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/445M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

`mvn vaadin:compile`

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building webrp 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> vaadin-maven-plugin:7.6.7:compile (default-cli) @ webrp >>>
[WARNING] The POM for jta:jta:jar:1.0.1 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/apache/velocity/velocity/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/apache/velocity/velocity/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 0.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public/com/google/guava/guava/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public/com/google/guava/guava/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 6.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- vaadin-maven-plugin:7.6.7:update-theme (default) @ webrp ---
[INFO] Theme processing is skipped
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< vaadin-maven-plugin:7.6.7:compile (default-cli) @ webrp <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- vaadin-maven-plugin:7.6.7:compile (default-cli) @ webrp ---
[INFO] GWT compilation is skipped
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.714s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Aug 09 12:12:23 MSK 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/438M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

`mvn vaadin:update-widgetset`

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building webrp 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for jta:jta:jar:1.0.1 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/apache/velocity/velocity/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/apache/velocity/velocity/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 1.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public/com/google/guava/guava/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public/com/google/guava/guava/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 6.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- vaadin-maven-plugin:7.6.7:update-widgetset (default-cli) @ webrp ---
[INFO] GWT compilation is skipped
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.175s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Aug 09 12:13:55 MSK 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/445M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

`MyAppWidgetset.gwt.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.5.1//EN"
        "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.5.1/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>
    <inherits name="com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet"/>
    <inherits name="org.tltv.gantt.WidgetSet" />
</module>
```

Comment: The error with Jsoup could indicate, that you have different/double/... Jsoup versions.

Comment: @cfrick I do not understand, what do you suggest? jsoup 1.8.3 included in dependencies in vaadin

Comment: He may be suggesting that you may have also defined a jsoup dependency in your pom, possibly with a different version than the vaadin transitive one. Furthermore, regarding the other issue did you [compile the vaadin widgetset](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/addons/addons-maven.html) `mvn vaadin:compile`?

Comment: @Morfic i updated question